# Casting String to Long in Scala in template play 2.0 template

Tags: templates, scala, playframework-2.0

How can I cast from a String to a long in a Scala play 2.0 template?

I want to do the following where I have the action: `Application.profile(Long user_id)`:

```
<a href='@routes.Application.profile((Long) session.get("user_id"))'>@session.get("username")</a>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Casting doesn't work like that in Scala.

You want:

```
session.get("user_id").toLong
```

Comment: Oh, well now I feel stupid haha. I got confused with scala's option class.

Comment: Don't worry, I was there just a few weeks ago! :)

Comment: toLong only works on String, but session.get("user_id") returns Option[String]

Comment: I had a similar situation, if session.get("user_id") returns Option[String], you can use session.get("user_id").toString.toLong

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13` you might prefer [`String::toLongOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toLongOption:Option[Long]) in order to safely handle `String`s which can't be cast to `Long`:

```
"1234".toLongOption.getOrElse(-1L) // 1234L
"lOZ1".toLongOption.getOrElse(-1L) // -1L
"1234".toLongOption                // Some(1234L)
"lOZ1".toLongOption                // None
```

In your case:

```
session.get("user_id").toLongOption.getOrElse(-1L)
```

---

With earlier versions, you can alternatively use a mix of `String::toLong` and `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try

Try("1234".toLong).getOrElse(-1L) // 1234L
Try("lOZ1".toLong).getOrElse(-1L) // -1L
```